# What should the resource be for ses:SendEmail and ses:SendRawEmail?

Tags: security, terraform, amazon-ses

I want to create a policy that allows sending email from `automated@example.org` to any email address.

Here is my policy:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ses_send" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "ses:SendEmail",
      "ses:SendRawEmail",
    ]

    resources = [
      "*",
    ]
  }
}
```

This works. However, I want to replace the wildcard resource with a concrete one.

**What should I put here?**

Note I am using Terraform, so can likely pull it from another resource, e.g. `aws_ses_email_identity`

Comment: I feel like this is documented very well in the AWS SES official documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/sending-authorization-policy-examples.html